# When should old comments referring to old software be flagged for removal?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags, old-questions

It's a safe bet that even the most locked down institutions have moved beyond IE 5.5. Should comments mentioning compatibility with severely obsolete versions of software, for example, be flagged?

[Here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers/7732309#comment9454024_7732309).

> nice. works in ie6 too. not ie5.5 though :-)

Answer (score 3):

If a technology has had several upgrades since the version the comment is referring to, it's likely it's no longer relevant. Commonsense applies. There's so much variation between frameworks, however the one thing about programming is, it changes rapidly. The fundamentals remain the same, but the peccadilloes for particular frameworks change with upgrades.

Any comment that is redundant can be flagged as "No Longer Needed". If there's a thread of archaic comments, then a custom comment flag can be raised requesting a comment thread clean up. It's also ok to flag each comment individually.

Comments are [transient](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment):

> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.

I always encourage people to not place an attachment on them. Comments can be buried in long comment threads. Put all necessary information into a question or answer. This is the safest way to ensure valuable information is not missed.